# jquery .height() is not returning the real value after the append function just called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to vertically align middle some pics using jquery.

Here is my code

```
$(".scroll a").hover(function (evt) {
  $("#box a").empty().append( 
    $('<img src='+this.href+' class="loadimg">')
  );
  vertical_align();
});
```

while the vertical align function is here

```
function vertical_align(){
  var child = $(".loadimg").height();
  var parent = $("#box").height();
  var margin = (parent - child)/2;
  $("#box a").children("img").css('margin-top', margin); 
}
```

Now the problem i am facing is that when the page is loaded, the `imageHeight` gives zero and the margin of the pic becomes half of the parent height which mean that `imageheight` is returning zero. But this only happens for the first time hover on each image.

Comment: Can you provide a demo? You could use [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: that would be a lot ov work to do again, the code makes it clear i guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this happens probably because you're reading the height too early, when at the first request the image isn't fully loaded. You should wait the load (or complete, from the 2nd request of the same image) event for the image, like so

```
$(".scroll a").hover(function (evt) {
     var node = $("#box a");
     node.empty(); 
     $('<img src='+this.href+' class="loadimg">')
       .appendTo(node)
       .one('load complete', function() {
           vertical_align();
       });

});
```

Comment: dude .. You r the BEstttt .. Awesome . Thanks a lott.. Can you please tell me if there is any alternative to this .one function that i could use?

Comment: well, `one()` just executes an handler once for element. So the event that first occurs is calling your function. An alternative is to unbind the event inside the handler itself